# Using a variable (?) to change color definition on STY file

Tags: color, conditionals, ifthenelse

I am trying to use a variable I define with `\newcommand` in a tex file (`\profile`) in an if-else loop to define a color (`\main_color`) in the style-file I am using. So when `\profile` is `np` `\main_color` should be Hex Code `2A4A97`, else it should be `a5003b`. I tried

```latex
\ifthenelse{\equal{\profile}{np}}
    {\definecolor{main_color}{HTML}{2A4A97}}
    {\definecolor{main_color}{HTML}{a5003b}}
```

but then I'm getting the following error: `! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \profile`

The MWE is as follows:

mwe.tex

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newcommand{\profile}{\detokenize{np}}            

\begin{document}

\customtitlepage

\section{Section One}

\blindtext
                       
\end{document}
```

The style used is this (mwe.sty):

```latex
\ProvidesPackage{mwe}
 
\RequirePackage[ngerman]{babel}
\RequirePackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage[]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}

% ---------------- Colors

\definecolor{main_color}{HTML}{2A4A97}

% \ifthenelse{\equal{\profile}{np}}
%     {\definecolor{main_color}{HTML}{2A4A97}}
%     {\definecolor{main_color}{HTML}{a5003b}}

% ---------------- Titlepage Definition 

\def\customtitlepage{
    \begin{titlepage}
    
        \raggedleft
        
        {\huge Title \vspace{0.25cm}}

        {\color{main_color}\rule{12cm}{3pt}} % Thick horizontal rule
        
        \vspace{2.5cm} 
        
        \raggedright
        
        {\huge \profile \vspace{0.25cm}}

        {\color{main_color}\rule{9.3cm}{3pt}} % Second Thick horizontal rule
        
        \vfill
        
        \centering
        
        Text
        
        \vfill
    
        \vspace{0.5cm}
        
        {\color{main_color}\rule{\textwidth}{3pt}}
        
        \vspace{1cm}
    \end{titlepage}
}
```

The tex files are generated automatically and `\profile` is used in several other places in the style, so I'd like to use it for this purpose as well.

Thanks!

Comment: You have to define `\profile` before loading your package.  But please don't name it `mwe.sty`: there is already a package with that name!

Comment: It's named differently ;) How do I do this? `{\huge \profile \vspace{0.25cm}}` picks up the value `np` corretcly from the tex file in the style

Comment: Because in that case `\profile` is inside a definition, so its definition doesn't matter.  It will only matter at the time the defined macro (`\customtitlepage`) is used.

Comment: Why don't you let your package define a macro that can be used after the package is loaded to set the colour? Something like `\newcommand\pickcolor[1]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{np}}{\definecolor...}{\definecolor...}}` and then use `\usepackage{mypkg}\pickcolor{np}` to set the correct colour.

Comment: thanks @Skillmon, your approach works fine for me!